# Laravel: Return non-relationship model data

Tags: laravel

I have `Character` Model. a `Character` can evolve, and I want to return the `Evolution` (Along with the character data) if the `Character` can Evolve.

This is how I do it in my `Character` Model:

```
public function evolution() 
    {
    return Evolution::where('character_id' , '=', $this->id)
            ->where('level', '<=', $this->level)
            ->first();
}
```

The problem is that I'm trying to return is with the `With` query keywoord (User Model) and it's not a relationship at all:

```
$userCharacters = UserCharacters::with('character')
        ->with('evolution')
        ->where('user_id','=',$this->id);
```

How I can output the evolution along with my `UserCharacter` without using `ForEach` (which adds it manually in the `Character` Model)?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with raw query.

That is,

```
DB:table('usercharacters')
->join('character','usercharacter.id','=','character_id')
->join('evolution','usercharacter.id','=','evolution_id')
->where('your_where_clause')
->first();
```

Comment: Please make sure you add the foreignkey id correctly. I have just shown you the syntax, how you can achieve.

Answer (score 0):

turn the function into a relation one:

```
public function evolution() 
{
    return $this->hasOne(Evolution::class,'character_id')->where('level', '<=', $this->level);
}
```